# Video orientation javascript

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

i am making a mobile project with angular-js and cordova. I want to add a feature that i want to show the video and it should rotate itself when i rotate the device to landscape or portrait, but i have a restriction, in the beginning of the app opening i am using lockOrientation(portrait) so i dont want to rotate any page to landscape, i only want to rotate videos not screen. i try to detect rotation with

```
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        alert("the orientation of the device is now " + screen.orientation.angle);
    });
```

and in css i can rotate the video below the code.

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
```

My question is how can i detect the orientation of the device while using lockOrientation? Is it possible? Because i can not unlock the orientation. I am a student and i am new to this environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with DeviceMotion plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device-motion/

```
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
          'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
          'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
}

function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}

var options = { frequency: 3000 };  // Update every 3 seconds

var watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

With acceleration i detected the device motion while the device is locked with portrait mode and made if checks to detect the device is in a portrait mode or in a landscape mode.